# How to manage access to AWS S3 resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, credentials

I am making both client and server for an application which will store files on S3. These files are generated by my application and are encrypted so they can only be opened by my application. They are to be bought in a store before downloading. To guarantee files are not passed around when downloaded each file is decrypted and encrypted again to be opened by that user's credentials only (this is done client-side).

I have already gotten a server running on EC2 with all the files in the local file system. The server checks an RDS database to see if a user has bought a file before sending it to him. I would like to move the file storage from EC2 to S3, and since transfer costs are much cheaper do them from S3 to the client directly.

Because of this, I need users to have access to specific files (only the ones they bought).

The way I am testing it right now is having an AWS user who can download objects from the S3 bucket, and be having the client configured with that user's access key and secret. This means that the AWS user's credentials are stored in the code of my application. Is this a safe thing to do? Since the client will download directly from S3, the S3 bucket should allow connections from any IP. This means that anyone who manages to get the credentials from my code will be able to download all cases (which in S3 will be encrypted to work with any user, so they could be redistributed).

Another option would be periodically changing this "download only" user's credentials and instead of having it fixed in the client's code, send the credentials from the EC2 server to the user each time (connection is encrypted with SSL).

Another option would be to create an aws user for each application user, and set his permissions on a per object basis. The credentials should be random and also sent to the client each time. This way if a user somehow gets hold of the credentials, he can only download and redistribute the cases he has bought.

Has anyone come across a similar problem? Which would be the best solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to stop hard-coding your AWS credentials in your code and use an IAM Role assigned to your EC2 server instead.

Any time a user needs to download a file you should generate a short-lived [S3 pre-signed URL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) on your EC2 server, and send that to the user's browser. The user will be able to download the file using the pre-signed URL, without any need to push AWS credentials up to the browser. The pre-signed URL will only be valid for a limited time (that you specify) so if the user tries to share the URL it won't work.

Comment: I saw this, but my applications are both c++ programs and I need to download the files to memory so I can encrypt them before saving them to disk. Is there a way of doing this from de c++ api?

Comment: Your C++ program runs on EC2? Or on some client's computer?

Comment: There is a server c++ program running on EC2, and a client c++ program running on the users's computer.

Comment: Do you have to encrypt the file on the user's computer before it is sent to EC2? Or do you perform the encryption on EC2?

Comment: If you need to encrypt/decrypt the files on your EC2 server, then all the files would need to be uploaded to the EC2 server and downloaded from the EC2 server. The EC2 server would be the only thing that has access to S3 and even knows that the files are on S3. If the files are encrypted/decrypted on the client, then having the server generate presigned URLs for the client will work fine.

Comment: Pre-signed URLs should work fine for you then. Generate them on the EC2 server and pass them to the client as needed. I don't see why needing to load the data in memory would restrict you from using pre-signed URLs.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it all working with pre-signed URLs. I guess I was just assuming there was a way of doing it straight from the C++ API without going through HTTP, so I was hesitant to use it at first.